# Can I assert on Lombok's @Slf4j logger?

Tags: java, lombok

Suppose I want to test that this method prints a `log.warn` message if the `Flux` is empty

```java
@Slf4j
class SomeClass {
    void someMethod(Flux<Integer> intFlux) {
        intFlux.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
            log.warn("No integers!");
            return Mono.empty();
        }))
        .subscribe(/* consume */);
    }
}
```

How can I do it? Specifically, how can I assert on Lombok's logger, if it's at all possible? It's not passed into the constructor, I can't `mock()` and `verify()`. Is it the only option to simply get rid of Lombok?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but are you looking for `LOGGER.warn`? The default name for generated logger object for @Slf4j annotation is LOGGER

Comment: @SwiftMango but it's not a mock, is it? How can Mockito keep track of what `LOGGER` does?

Answer (score 1):

Intercept sysout:

```
// pre test
PrintStream oldOut = System.out;
ByteArrayOutputStream capturedOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream newOut = new PrintStream(capturedOutput);
System.setOut(newOut);
// run tests
newOut.flush();
// restore sysout
System.setOut(oldOut);
String output = capturedOutput.toString();
// assert 'output' contains stuff
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually had that idea, but what if the logger doesn't log into standard output? Besides, I'd need to parse the string to assert on the logging level which is suboptimal

Comment: If it doesn't log to stdout, it will be to a file that your test can read in to a String, putting you in the same place as this. Asserting the contents of a String should be easy enough using `contains()` or `matches()`